# NFC Card reader in Virtualbox Unreliable

Tags: macos, timeout, virtualbox, nfc, reader

I am on Mac OS X and running Virtualbox. Inside the Virtualbox there's a debian (Kali Linux) which I am mapping a ACS ACR122U to, that is attached to the Host via USB.

It shows up:

```
root@kali:~/nfc# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 072f:2200 Advanced Card Systems, Ltd ACR122U
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And after I restart the pcscd process it works Once or twice but then fails. The next time I try it is working again:

```
root@kali:~/nfc# nfc-list 
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
NFC device: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
root@kali:~/nfc# nfc-list 
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
NFC device: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
root@kali:~/nfc# nfc-list 
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_usb:001:004
root@kali:~/nfc# nfc-list 
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
NFC device: ACS / ACR122U PICC Interface opened
root@kali:~/nfc# nfc-list 
nfc-list uses libnfc 1.7.1
nfc-list: ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: acr122_usb:001:004
```

For whatever reason it produces timeouts. This also shows up in the pcscd log:

```
0000021 ccid_usb.c:1246:InterruptRead() libusb_submit_transfer failed: LIBUSB_ERROR_IO
03423517 ccid_usb.c:822:ReadUSB() read failed (1/5): -7 LIBUSB_ERROR_TIMEOUT
00000587 ifdwrapper.c:369:IFDStatusICC() Card not transacted: 612
00000446 eventhandler.c:333:EHStatusHandlerThread() Error communicating to: ACS ACR122U PICC Interface 00 00
```

I have no Idea how this happens but it's a pain because once I try to use `nfc-mfclassic` or `mfoc` or whatever it will break in the process because of the timeouts.

I have tried rebooting the machine, `nfs` and `pn533` are blacklisted and I tried setting the USB controller to USB1 and USB3 in the virtualbox settings. Suggestions?

Comment: Since you are using the acr122_usb driver in libnfc, why would you want to run pcscd? These two typically block eachother since both try to access the USB device directly...

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought it would be necessary. Additionally without the pcscd it does not work at all.

Comment: I have this identical problem. The device works from macos and on a raspberry pi but has the same symptoms in kali in both parallels and virtualbox